# Best way to convert title into url compatible mode in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, url

I would like to use the title of my Posts to create a readable URL like

Given a title "Olá Pessoas!"

http://mydomain.com.br/store/ola-pessoas

I've found useful examples in PHP but if anybody had faced this quest and has a solution in Haskell, I would appreciate your solution instead of just starting from zero comparing with the solutions I found in other languages.

Comment: This is called a slug. Haskell has a `slug` package: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/slug-0.1.7/docs/Web-Slug.html

Comment: Willen Van Onsem Thank you a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for, I don't understand why did my question get so many down votes, but you answered it perfectly and if you make an answer with this comment I will mark as right!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why did my question get down votes, if it was created after a PHP question like this and PHP community gave answers ... Willen Van Onsem answered what I need: `This is called a slug. Haskell has a slug package: hackage.haskell.org/package/slug-0.1.7/docs/Web-Slug.html`